# White spaces being added to text

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm currently using a django char field in a model to store a url and then in the templates I do this:

```
{% block url %}
{% if object.url== '' %}
    {{ object.old_url}}
{% else %}
    {{ object.url.strip }}
{% endif %}
{% end block url %}
```

We define the url block in a different file called base which the above extends this is the code in base where the block url is being defined

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="{% block url %}{{ {{ request.get_full_path }}{% endblock %}" />
```

When i check it using inspect in chrome dev tools there are trailing and leading whitespaces for some reason even thought the "url" we enter has no whitespaces starting out? is their anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what the context where you see this whitespace ? into HTML tag ? in input value ? Else ?

Comment: for e.g.:     <link rel="url" href="  https://abcd.com " />  is what i get instead of it having no whitespace

Comment: Can you please, show the template code with the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your block is set in a parent template like that:

```html
<link rel="url" href="{% block url %}{% endblock %}" />
```

so in this case, it is normal you have space after template rendering with the example code you have set in your post. Spaces between each conditions blocks are kept by the rendering process of django. You can inline condition or trying use `spaceless` django tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless)

```
{% block url %}{% if object.url== '' %}{{ object.old_url}}{% else %}{{ object.url.strip }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```